# iOS 11 reminder completely broken, not working

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

Yet another major major bug with the simplest app such as reminder. I can't set the reminder for certain time. I can set it, but as soon as I go out, and in again to the Reminder app, it gets resetted and doesn't have the date set to be triggered. Completely useless app. Does anyone know how to set a reminder on an iPhone with iOS 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I had to delete the app and re-install it from the App Store.
Then Reminders started working normally.

Comment: I can accept this, as it worked for you.